# Two parameters in a predicate function

Tags: python-3.x, predicate

Is there a way that I can write a predicate function that will compare two strings and see which one is greater? Right now I have

```
def helper1(x, y):
    return x > y
```

However, I'm trying to use the function in this way,

`new_tuple = divide((helper1(some_value, l[0]),l[1:])`

Please note that the above function call is probably wrong because my helper1 is incomplete. But the gist is I'm trying to compare two items to see if one's greater than the other, and the items are `l[1:]` to `l[0]`

Divide is a function that, given a predicate and a list, divides that list into a tuple that has two lists, based on what the predicate comes out as. Divide is very long, so I don't think I should post it on here.

So given that a predicate should only take one parameter, how should I write it so that it will take one parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a closure.

```
def helper(x):
  def cmp(y):
    return x > y
  return cmp

 ...
new_tuple = divide(helper1(l[0]), l[1:])
 ...
```